# How to automatically resize AutoComplete field in Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I want to implement an AutoComplete field using Material UI, where the size of the field resizes according to the option selected.

[image]

When the option selected does not occupy the entire field, I would like the size of the field to reduce. And if the option selected is longer than what the field can accommodate, I would like the field size to increase to display the entire option

[image]

How can this be implemented in Material UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input width can be changed by creating a State variable.

```
const [inputWidth, setInputWidth] = useState(DEFAULT_INPUT_WIDTH);
```

where

```
const DEFAULT_INPUT_WIDTH = 90;
```

can be set to any default value. Ex: 90

In addition, create a const for the **font size**

```
const FONT_SIZE = 9;
```

The Props taken by autocomplete take a width value for the TextField. Set the width of the field in the style attribute.

```
let autocompleteInputProps = {
      label: 'ABC',
      style: { width: `${inputWidth}px`},  
    };
```

Whichever function that handles the select change will include the following code

```
const handleSelectChange = (value) => {
    if (value.code.toString().length !== 1){
      setInputWidth(DEFAULT_INPUT_WIDTH + value.toString().length * FONT_SIZE)
    } else {
      setInputWidth(DEFAULT_INPUT_WIDTH)
    }
  };
```

[This](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-mqdib?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&file=/demo.js:127-159) explains the same in TextField.